# How to integrate $ f(x,y) $ over a polygon?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been given a polygon with corner points' coordinates and a line $Ax+By+C=0$ that splits that polygon into two. I want to integrate a function $f(x,y)$ over one of the resulting polygons.

$$f(x,y)=-\frac{ag(x,y)^2}{b}\ + \frac {ag(x,y)^3}{3b^2},$$ where $g(x,y)$ is simply the distance to the cutting line.

I know it is possible using Green's theorem but my knowledge is not enough to use it. Can you please solve it for me?

If  $$\frac{ \partial \ F(x,y)}{ \partial \ y}\ =f(x,y).$$ 
Can I say $$\int f(x,y) dxdy = \int F(x,y)dx \;?$$

Comment: No you can't say that. If $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = f$, then $F(x,y)+g(x)$ has the same partial derivative w.r.t. to $y$ for an arbitrary function for $x$.